# Caroufredsel pagination text?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, caroufredsel

I am using the carouFredsel plugin in a pretty basic way - 4 slides with copy, 4 tabs on the side to serve as "navigation" between the slides. This plugin has a build-in pagination function that automatically builds pagination with the numbers 1-x as the text you can click on to go to that slide. I need custom text to be in there -- and have spent a long time trying to figure out a way, but can't see one. I am a novice with Jquery. 
Also I should mention I am pulling in the slide content dynamically through Wordpress, but do not need dynamic pagination copy. Any solution will do!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    // Using custom configuration
    $j("#home-banner").carouFredSel({
        items               : 1,
        direction           : "left",
        auto : {
            play            :false,
        },
        pagination          : "#home-banner_pag",
        scroll : {
            items           : 1,
            fx              : "fade",
            duration        : 200
        }                   

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `pagination: "#home-banner_pag",` width

`pagination: {anchorBuilder: function(nr) { return '<a href="#"><span>'+'custom text here'+nr+'</span></a>'; }},`

Didn't tested but should be like that.

Comment: This did end up being the solution with a slight alteration. I had to add the target container, and then put in a variable to spit out the appropriate copy for each link. Thanks for your help!

`pagination: {
    anchorBuilder: function(nr) { return '<a href="#"><span>'+'<?php echo $banner_link_copy ?>'+nr+'</span></a>'; },
    container : "#home-banner_pag",
   },`

Comment: You can check the uncompressed js file for the library ... all becomes clear there :) You can vote up if you think this answer was helpful :)